# transform 2 txt files in igraph oblect in R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-visualization

Good afternoon.
I have 2 txt files. One containing one column the nodes and the other links( multiple columns separated by spaces containing 0(no links) and 1(directed links). I do not have any kind of headers in the files.
I want to import in R and transform them in graph object.
Example of node file.(column 1)

```
135
246
358
```

....

Example of links file.(multiple columns)

```
0     0      0     1     0
1     0      1     0     0
0     0      0     0     0
```

...........................

I tried https://kateto.net/network-visualization  but with no success.
I convert them in Excel but no success.
Please I need you help...

Comment: The number of rows must be equal to the number of columns. Is the adjacency matrix like you have posted? If not give a better example, please.

Comment: yes they are....I just gave an example. I have 128 rows with one column that is just the gene code and the other txt file is 128x128 . Exist way maybe to attach the 2 files here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of creating a graph from two files, one with the nodes names and the other with the adjacency matrix.

Suppose the files names are as follows:

```
nodesfile <- "nodes.txt"
linksfile <- "links.txt"
```

Since they are to be read in as a vector and as a matrix, respectively, function `scan` can be used.

```
nodes <- scan(file = nodesfile, what = character())
links <- scan(file = linksfile)
```

Now first coerce the *vector* `links` above to a matrix and then create the graph. The code below assumes the graph is directed, see `help("graph_from_adjacency_matrix")`.

```
library(igraph)

links <- matrix(links, 
                nrow = length(nodes), 
                byrow = TRUE,
                dimnames = list(nodes, nodes))

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(links)
plot(g)
```

Comment: Perfect you are amazing! I ve got the graph! But g is now an igraph object?

Comment: @Adam Yes, `g` is an igraph object, try `class(g)`.

Comment: All are ok but when I try to analyse the graph    visualize_graph( g, centrality.type="Barycenter Centrality") with CINNA package, I am getting error Error in visualize_graph(g, centrality.type = "Barycenter Centrality") : 
  The input is not an igraph object or may not be connected.

Comment: @Adam It *is* an igraph object. Only you can tell if it is connected with functions like [these](https://igraph.org/r/doc/components.html). And if not, decompose it in connected components.

Comment: Οκ . Ι am going to try this. Thank you!